# ListBox is Not Automatically Expanding with Dynamic Data Adding through 'PhoneTextBox' wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, mvvm, listbox, dynamic-data

I would like to perform something's like fb comment Layout.

[image]

and I am Using Following Code To perform this task :

// Constructor

```
    string []content;
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        content = new string[11] { "Great stories produce the ideas which help children to know how the cleverness and wise decisions take the people out of the dangerous and most tricky situations.", 
                                   "No virtue is as noble as kindness. The stories “Prince Frog”, “Dove and the ant” and others teaches them the importance of being kind to even to the small god made creatures of this earth.", 
                                   "Honesty is a key to success and honest people are duly rewarded. These stories show honesty is a most beautiful quality to be possessed, liked and appreciated.",
                                   "Humbleness makes us kind hearted and soft spoken- the virtues which will always be deemed and valued in the eyes of the others.",
                                   "Realize the importance of hard work through these evergreen stories. These popular stories are the inroads to the very roots of the concept “Hard work is a road to success.",
                                   "If you speak the truth, your children will speak too.  This would help them built the trust and reputation in their society and around them.",
                                   "Courageous child can easily cross each milestones of life with ease, then why not we too help our children to be strong for the others too to follow.",
                                   "True Friendship is a God’s precious gift and a commitment for togetherness, and sharing and caring.",
                                   "Understand the value of being united, to overcome any difficult situation and understand the meaning of working in a team and grow as a virtuous and a strong human being.",
                                   "Obeying the elders will ultimately be good for you.  Stories like \"Three goats and the Wolf\" can help your children understand the value of being obedient.",
                                   "Greediness leads to destruction. It causes obsession which is more harmful. Let us know how through these great stories."  };

        populate_list();

    }

    private void populate_list()
    {           
        for (int i = 0; i < content.Length; i++)
        {
            //mainlist.Items.Add(content[i]);
            var maintext = new TextBlock();
            maintext.Text = content[i];
            maintext.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;

            StackPanel stkpanel = new StackPanel();
            stkpanel.Width = 480;
            stkpanel.Height = 124;

            stkpanel.Children.Add(maintext);

            var expander = new ExpanderView();

            var phonetextbox = new PhoneTextBox();
            phonetextbox.Hint = "Add a Comment";
            phonetextbox.ActionIcon = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri("/search.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

            StackPanel stkpanel_new = new StackPanel();
            stkpanel_new.Width = 480;

            phonetextbox.ActionIconTapped += (s, e) =>                 
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(phonetextbox.Text))
                {
                    expander.Items.Add(phonetextbox.Text);
                    expander.IsExpanded = true;

                    //stkpanel_new.Height = stkpanel_new.Height + 20;
                }
            }; 

            stkpanel_new.Children.Add(phonetextbox);
            stkpanel_new.Children.Add(expander);

            mainlist.Items.Add(stkpanel);
            mainlist.Items.Add(stkpanel_new);

        }
    }
```

But i Got problem on Dynamic Comment insertion when user entered text in phonetextbox and press on its Icon the comment just added behind the listbox 2nd element (means ExpanderView will be expanded but listbox further elements are not adjusting it dynamically ).

Am i Doing Something wrong or it is a Framework limitation ?? Help .

Regards

Pardeep Sharma

Comment: HI Guys,

I have shared my code on below sky drive link, please check it and save my life :

link : http://sdrv.ms/1a5Zc0l

folder name: diary_list

regards,

Pardeep sharma

Answer (score 0):

for this type of dynamic height I recommend the longlistselector control, which is useful in both orientation and for main container use Grid that will set it self as per content's size because its height is by default "Auto"

Comment: Hi @techloverr, As i mentioned above i am populating my list dynamically, with longlistselector we don't have any Items.Add(); method to add items dynamically. we could only create ItemTemplate with static data in LongListSelector(as per my knowledge.)

Comment: yea but if you bind observable collection with LLS than if you add item in that collection it will automatically update the UI , so your requirement will be fulfilled

Answer (score 0):

Replacing you action handler by this one should fix your problem:

```
phonetextbox.ActionIconTapped += (s, e) =>                 
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(phonetextbox.Text))
            {
                expander.Items.Add(phonetextbox.Text);
                this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => {
                       expander.IsExpanded = true;
                });

                //stkpanel_new.Height = stkpanel_new.Height + 20;
            }
        };
```

but you should really look into using mvvm. One of the big downside of your implementation (among a lot of others architectural benefit) is that you are going to lost the benefit of UI virtualisation (A ListBox don't build all the ui element of all the items just the one into view and a little more but since you are creating them all your self you lost that benefit).

Comment: Hi Benoit, U couldn't understand my problem let me brief 'when i entered multiple elements through expander view it just overlap with next list items and that'll cause some freaky layout' . By adding dispatcher we cannot solve the problem and moreover with MVVM n virtualisation i'll implement it on separate layer.

Comment: I actually tested your code and was seeing the same thing your are describing and adding a dispatcher at the place I added it was fixing the problem for me but maybe the problem is not exactly the same on your device...

Comment: Actually I just saw thaat you uploaded you whole project and tested, the other problem is that you are not using the latest version of the window phone toolkit (that you could get from nuget for example) just upgrade it and it should work